# Left animation shift when using nested NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am developing an application using SwiftUI (XCode 12.5.1) and every time one of my View appears after exactly two links of "NavigationLink" everything that is inside a `Form` is shifted slightly to the left, once the appearing animation is over. The following video shows whats going on : the first two times I open the view, everything is fine. The next two times, when the view is accessed from nested NavigationLink, a slight shift to the left is done once the appearing animation is over.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k3gjc42xlqp2auf/leftShift.mov?dl=0

I have the same problem on both the simulator and a real device (an iPhone). Here is the project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8r5hktg6lz69ob/Bug.zip?dl=0 . The main code is available below.

Here is the main view `ContentView.swift`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: PersonView()) {
                    Text("Person")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: IndirectView()) {
                    Text("Indirect")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here is the indirect view, `IndirectView.swift`

```
import SwiftUI

struct IndirectView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: PersonView()) {
                Text("Person")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the person view, `PersonView.swift`

```
import SwiftUI

struct PersonView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text("Last Name")
                    .font(.system(.subheadline))
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                Text("Fayard")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea on what's causing this shift?

Thanks for your help

Francois

Comment: Have you tested this on a real device? Past that, you need a minimal reproducible example as this will take some playing with in Xcode unless someone has happened to hit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly saying I have not idea what causes the problem, but here is the fix: add this line of code no your NavigaitonView

```
NavigationView {
// everything else
}.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```